# JSP - Redirect while keeping request attribute

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a basic login form that asks for a username and password.
The information is passed to a servlet, but if it's invalid I want the servlet to redirect back to the login page.

At the moment the servlet is doing this:

```
else{
    request.setAttribute("error","Username or password incorrect");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

I need that `error` attribute to be set so that I can have an alert on the login page when the user is redirected back there:

```
<div style="color: red">${error}</div>
```

While a valid login is fine, an invalid one sits on `/LoginServlet?user=test&pswd=test`, whereas I want it to simply sit on `/Login.jsp`

I know that this is because I'm using `forward` instead of `response.sendRedirect` (I use this for a valid logon), but using the latter causes me to loose my `error` attribute.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a workaround, but it requires extra functionality. What you are describing is known as the Flash Scope. We want to keep an attribute so that it is available in the next request. This is usually done in POST-REDIRECT-GET scenarios.

The Servlet API doesn't have such functionality so we have to implement it ourselves. You can do it with a `Filter` as described [here](http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2011/01/implementing-flash-scope-in-java-web-applications/).

Basically, you add the attribute to the `HttpSession` on your first request. On the next one, you copy it from the `HttpSession` into the `HttpServletRequest` attributes and clear it from the `HttpSession`.

Comment: url returns a 404

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion of forward vs actual redirect and the limited scope of request attributes is correct.  You could make your error thing a Session attribute, which would let you reference it from Login.jsp on the redirect, but now you have the added problem of clearing it once you use it to render Login.jsp.  Its not horrible, but just another thing you need to remember to do.

Rock, hard place.  The problem with the URL not being Login.jsp on the error case is what?

Comment: The problem with the URL is that is shows the password, which is the main thing I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: AHHH!  Well then, maybe the Session thing isn't all that bad.  Or maybe Redirect to Login.jsp passing error=Username+or+password+ incorrect as a parameter